# How make 2 option in menu dropdown in excel with formula and without formula?

Tags: excel

I want to create a dropdown menu, where there are two options;

1. I have to manually input a value which will generate a percentage based on the value data I have on the next sheet.
2. Automatically input values based on the percentage of the value on the next sheet.

Is this possible in the dropdown menu?

[sheet Insurance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maJa0.png)

[sheet income](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KquVc.png)

how should i simplify it?

Answer (score 1):

Have two cells, one with the value you manually enter, the other with the value from the other sheet.

In a third cell use Data Validation to pick between the two cells - the list option will work.